# How to expand the right width of a div?

Tags: html, css

I want to expand the right width of a div to 100% (look at the screenshot, my div is red), I have tried with:

HTML example:

```
<header>
    <nav>
        <ul>
            <li>Menu</li>
            <li>Menu</li>
            <li>Menu</li>
        </ul>
    </nav>
    <aside>
        <h1>Logo</h1>
    <aside>
</header>
```

CSS:

```
header {
    width: 1024px;
    height: 395px;
    margin: 0 auto;
}

nav {
    height: 60px;
    width: 690px;

    position: absolute;
    top: 20px;
    right: 0;

    background:red;
}
```

This works fine but when i try to zoom out (ctrl -) the menu navigation list go out from the container. The logo remains centered but nav not.

Thanks for any help!
and sorry for my bad english.

[image: click here]

Comment: Your markup doesn't contain a div

Comment: @KevinBowersox The code above was an example.

Comment: Put your actual code in a fiddle so it's more clear what the problem is. http://jsfiddle.net/

Comment: @isherwood http://jsfiddle.net/5nfZ5/ now try to zoom out and you will see what the problem is.

Comment: just put float:right if you want them on right...if you them to cover all screen,then put width:100% http://jsfiddle.net/5nfZ5/1/

Comment: The provided example markup does not reproduce the issue as stated in the question, try giving the maximum possible code so that we can reproduce the issue and try helping out.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are looking for this: [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/cemozer/LEkCu/). Put `position: relative` to your header. After that your nav's positioning will behave relative to your header. And for the correct alignment change your nav's `top: 20px` to `top: 0`.

Answer (score 0):

If you want that red bar will always extend to the right margin of window, even if you enlarge and narrow the Browser window, you can set width of this bar to a very high value (for example 500%). This will extend bar a lot to right but will add an horizontal scrollbar.
So set the following to simply hide overflow:

```
html,body
{
   overflow-x:hidden;
}
```